# Simple way to encrypt MySQL data in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, encryption

We have a MySQL database where some tables contain sensitive information (e.g. user emails and ID numbers). We would like to encrypt these tables. We read the [relevant part in the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-data-encryption.html), but were overwhelmed by the different options and configurations. Is there a simple how-to guide that shows what commands we should use to have the MySQL tables encrypted in Ubuntu?

We have Ubuntu 22.04 and MySQL 8.0.33.

Comment: I would have asked that on https://dba.stackexchange.com/   The OS is no part of this kind of encryption. "Is there a simple how-to guide that shows what commands we should use to have the MySQL tables encrypted in Ubuntu?" Google suggests  https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/controlling-table-encryption-in-mysql-8-0/  but no, " in Ubuntu" ... this is a mysql command line issue

Comment: @Rinzwind the relevance to Ubuntu is due to the specifics of the installation of MySQL. For example, the MySQL documentation says "create a global manifest file named mysqld.my in the mysqld installation directory, and optionally create a local manifest file, also named mysqld.my, in the data directory", but I do not know where these directories are on Ubuntu.

Comment: so your question is not how to encrypt but where those config files are? You should already know that ...  you have a mysql.conf  you set up on 1st install and that holds all  directories. The whole of MySQL is dynamic and OS independent.  "but I do not know where these directories are on Ubuntu" that is a bad thing to say: You already should know everything about your server,

Comment: @Rinzwind I just made the default install..